# Hair particle not covering the whole mesh

Tags: mesh, particles, hair

I want to learn a little bit more about hair paticles. At the moment I want to cover an object completely in fur, but some parts of the mesh is not covered right now.
I tried to recalculate normals, remesh the whole object and also tried the "Use modifier stack" option in the particle system (This was the solution in a question I found on stackexchange) but nothing really worked.

Does anybody knows what the problem is and has a solution for me?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello maybe share the object: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots I added the link in the question :)

Comment: it looks like pure hasard, if you change the seed this part will have hair, I guess you need to switch to Particle Edit and use the Add brush to correct that?

Comment: @moonboots Mhh okay. I thought this was a mistake in the process of creating the mesh or the particle system :D Then I need to place them all by hand haha. Thx for the help!

Comment: I may miss something though... anyway, editing the hair will fix the problem